# How to show that $f-g$ is imaginary constant in $\mathbb{D}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How to show that $f-g$ is imaginary constant in $\mathbb{D}$?
Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous functions in $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$ and analytic in $\mathbb{D}$. Show that if $\mathfrak{R}f=\mathfrak{R}g$ at $\partial \mathbb{D}$, then $f-g$ is imaginary constant at $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$.

some hint, please.

I have found that if $f(z)=z^2$ and $g(z)=z^2-i$, then $\mathfrak{R}f=x^2-y^2=\mathfrak{R}g$ and $f-g=i$, which is imaginary constant $\forall z \in \bar{\mathbb{D}} \subset C$.

Comment: **Hint**: $\Re f$, $\Re g$ are harmonic. Use Cauchy-Riemann.

Comment: Aynab Hourieh: do you mean that use C-R equations on $u$ and $v$ of function $f=u+iv$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real part of a holomorphic function is harmonic. So $u = \Re(f-g)$ is harmonic, and equal to zero on the boundary $\partial \mathbb{D}$ of the unit disk. But by the [maximum principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_principle) for harmonic functions, $u$ must attain its minimum and its maximum on $\partial \mathbb{D}$, meaning $\max u = \min u = 0 \implies u = 0$.

By the Cauchy–Riemann equations, for $v = \Im(f-g)$, you get $\partial v / \partial x = \partial v / \partial y = 0$, hence $v$ is constant and $f-g = iv$ is constant imaginary.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Maximum Modulus Theorem

More hint: look at the function $e^{f -g}$